UCI_German_Credit_Data attributes descriptions
It has been a few hours I am exploring the [GermanCreditData](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/dataset/144/statlog+german+credit+data) and yet I did not find a exact description of what the "Attribute2" column should represent.
The documentations says:
"Attribute 2 (numerical):
Duration in month"

Is it the duration of a loan, the checking-account duration since opened ... ?

Is there any thorough analysis over the dataset on the internet ?


Since Attribute3 shows us the credit history AND each line represents a loaner, either it represents the duration of only the last/first/longest loan or the duration their checking account has been active for.
But checking the rows where the loaner doesn't have an active checking account (Attribute1 == 'A14'), I could note that those rows still had values in their Duration column. Someone without an account shouldn't have any number on their Duration column, so I could interpret the Attribute2 as the duration for a past/last/actual loan.
However, I cannot feel granted with inferences. But searching through the internet I only found reproductions of the shallow description given by author.
